# Is there a way to disable globals?

Tags: c++, debugging, global-variables

I have a rather lengthy legacy code function. Is there any way to check if it is using any global variables or disable access to any?

Comment: How about putting it in its own source file?

Comment: just guessing - cpplint or cppcheck ?

Comment: @wroniasty, as for cppcheck, I think no, at least not if you don't plan to write your own rules. What I do instead is just removing the variable definitions and check were code fails.

Comment: @honk Yeah, but in my case there are too many globals for that approach. :)

Comment: @VaughnCato The problem is that I need includes and those usually pull in the nasty globals.

Comment: You could possibly forward-declare or stub anything that the function uses to avoid #includes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would check for data symbols in the generated object file: `nm -po file.o | grep ' D '` The compiler generates a couple of symbols and you probably want to check for a couple of other kind of symbols, e.g. `B` and lowercase versions.

Answer (score 0):

On Linux, compile your executable as you normally would, then run:

```
nm your-program | egrep " (b|B) "
```

This will list the symbols in the [BSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.bss).